# Java - SWT - Why i must use absolute path in this case?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

I'm developing an SWT application. I met this strange error. Suppose I have:

```
public class ShellCenter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(200, 200);

        imgData = new ImageData("src/main/resources/images/edit.png");
        buttonImg = new Image(composite.getDisplay(), imgData);
        addButton.setImage(buttonImg);

        A newA = new A();

        shell.setLocation(x, y);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}

public class A
{
    imgData = new ImageData("src/main/resources/images/edit.png");
    buttonImg = new Image(composite.getDisplay(), imgData);
    editButton.setImage(buttonImg);
}
```

Then whenever I change the perspective from source code to design (I use Eclipse and WindowBuilder), I get the message "file not found" for the path in class A but when I run this application it still runs properly, the button's icon still appears. If I want to use the design view I must change that path to an absolute path like: `D:/ ... /edit.png` . I'm sure that the file's path is ok, because it's used everywhere in the main method and I have no error, but when it's in another class I'm facing that problem.

Comment: Note that if you are intending to build a jar containing the code and resources this will fail when everything is in the jar. Objects in jars are not files and can't be accessed this way.

Comment: I'm building an SWT window application since i have a TabFolder with TabItem contains other controls (such as: button, table, label...). So i create a class extends from TabItem that contain those control so if it's easy for me to use that Tab Item in other places. The problems is that, if i put that path in the tab item class i will get this error, the program still run properly but i can't use the window builder any more due to the find not found error as i mentioned above.

Comment: As greg-449 already hinted at, to target files in jars you would use something like `A.class.getResource("images/edit.png")`. Maybe this is the way the WindowBuilder expects internal resources to be adressed. Give it a try ;)

Comment: i have try to pass an image data to A class but it's not working